# Searchbar enlarges on click with grey shaded area

Tags: ios

I have a searchdisplaycontroller which enlarges on click with gray shaded area and also searchbar disappears on typing .How to fix this?

Comment: probably, you have to post your code for someone to help you.

Comment: Tableview.alpha = 1 set to textfield Delegate method's